# Database Not being created using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am trying to create a Db using Entity Framework, when I run the program the DB is not being created, am I missing something as i have been dwelling with this problem for some time now.

Code below:

Database:

```
class SchoolEmployeesContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolEmployeesContext()
        : base("SchoolEmployeesDB") { }

    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee :

```
abstract class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCommencement { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Department DepartmentOfEmployee { get; set; }

    public Employee NewEmployee(Employee NewEmp)
    {
        return NewEmp;
    }

}
```

Department :

```
class Department
{
    public Department() { }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> EmployeesAtDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where are your migrations?

Comment: Where's your initialization and seeding code? The code you posted isn't relevant, it just shows a context and some classes.

Comment: Do you have a [Context initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)?

Comment: Can you show SchoolEmployeesDBContext.cs?

Comment: @Sasha  class SchoolEmployeesContext : DbContext
    {
        SchoolEmployeesContext ctx = new SchoolEmployeesContext();

        public SchoolEmployeesContext()
            : base("SchoolEmployeesDB"){}

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @Chanter can you paste as code in your question?

Comment: @Sasha its the first part of the question

Comment: @Chanter, sorry, do you have there OnModelCreating method? Or may be you can try to override it and try create few enteties to see if it will be working?

Comment: @Sasha I tried to create a bit of entities for both, but still no db

Comment: @Chanter please share your full code example, if possible in a git repo, that's easier for us to look at..

Comment: @Chanter and what error do you get? May be something wrong with connectionString

Comment: @YvesSchelpe Setting up Github, will share in a moment

Comment: @Sasha No errors, Program runs fine with the exception of having no DB created

Answer (score 0):

EF will only trigger making a database in your application when you instantiate the DbContext class. So to trigger that, make sure to call `new SchoolEmployeesContext()` in for example `static void main()`. Although *that is not the recommended place*, but that was not your core question ofourse.

There are other options, e.g.

- using migrations and using the command `Database-Update`
- using migrations and using the command `Database-Update -Script` to get the T-SQL generated by EF to create the database

Comment: can you share your project structure on git(-hub, -lab, *) maybe, or share an error (if you're getting one)?

Comment: also, what version of EF are you using?

Comment: ok - if you can't share us more information on your project structure we can't help out...

Answer (score 0):

Put this in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ....
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolEmployeesContext>());
       }
```

Test your code with this:

```
 try
           {
                using (database = new SchoolEmployeesContext())
                {
                    var data = database.Departments.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
```

If your DB has not been created you will get an exception with the reason.